# Python change cpt on save with Wand

Tags: python, imagemagick, wand

I have the following function to convert PDF to images :

```
from wand.image import Image as Img
    with Img(filename=pdfName, resolution=self.resolution) as pic:
    pic.compression_quality = self.compressionQuality
    pic.background_color    = Color("white")
    pic.alpha_channel       = 'remove'
    pic.save(filename='full_' + random + '-%03d.jpg')
```

If the PDF is multi page the JPG files are like this :

`file-000.jpg`, `file-001.jpg`

My question is, is it possible to have a cpt starting at 1 ?

`file-001.jpg`, `file-002.jpg`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update

Another option is to set the [`Image.scene`](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.6.1/wand/image.html#wand.image.BaseImage.scene)

```py
from wand.image import Image as Img
from wand.api import library

with Img(filename=pdfName, resolution=self.resolution) as pic.
    # Move the internal iterator to first frame.
    library.MagickResetIterator(pic.wand)
    pic.scene = 1
    pic.compression_quality = self.compressionQuality
    pic.background_color    = Color("white")
    pic.alpha_channel       = 'remove'
    pic.save(filename='full_' + random + '-%03d.jpg')
```

### Original

<s>The only thing</s> I can think of is putting an empty image on the stack before reading.

```py
with Img(filename='NULL:') as pic:
    pic.read(filename=pdfName, resolution=self.resolution)
    pic.compression_quality = self.compressionQuality
    pic.background_color    = Color("white")
    pic.alpha_channel       = 'remove'
    pic.save(filename='full_' + random + '-%03d.jpg')
```

This would put a `file-000.jpg`, but it would be empty, and you can quickly remove it with `os.remove()`

Comment: Perfect for the second one :D